# How to change to dark theme on Bootstrap Resume?

Tags: html, css, themes, darkmode

I made my site recently, using this template: https://startbootstrap.com/theme/resume

I've seen that the `styles.css` file has `-dark` elements alongside its `-light` elements, for a potential dark theme. My question is, how do I use these? Is there a line in the css file I'm missing, or should I add a line in the html file?

Answer (score 0):

- You may need to make use of scss custom styling: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#color-schemess
- I also took a look to the source code from https://startbootstrap.com/theme/resume (and the comment section for people asking for dark theme; no answer from the author) and he's using scss as well while in development. He's using Bootstrap with little to no modification starting with his scss files in his repository: https://github.com/startbootstrap/startbootstrap-resume
- I think that your best solution is implementing some additional custom styling from a 3rd party project like: https://vinorodrigues.github.io/bootstrap-dark-5/
- You can also try the approach suggested here: https://blog.shhdharmen.me/toggle-light-and-dark-themes-in-bootstrap using some JS code.